# VBA Excel Error 424 with collection object reference

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, collections, controls

So I am creating a User form which collects data and will use that data to generate a report. There are a lot of questions that the user is asked. Specifically, there are blocks of questions about a test on this form which are identical. Numerous exist so that the user can input information about numerous tests on the form. I am relatively new to VBA excel, and I could not figure out how to make a class module for all of the repetitive question blocks. Consequently, I have made 8. the questions in each block are named differently by a number, for example: TestType1_ComboBox, TestType2_ComboBox, and so on.

Yes, I realize this is highly inefficient, but I had too much trouble setting up the class modules.

I want to be able to reference all of the X_ComboBoxes for example so I can AddItem's to all of them easily with a loop. I made a collection so I could reference all of the TestType_ComboBoxes for efficiency. I plan on doing this type of reference for all of the controls in the 8 question blocks.

Problem: I get the 424 object reference error when I try to reference an object in a collection.

```
''' create collections:
Public ttComboBox As Collection
Public ttAmountBlocked As Collection
Public ttgcFileName As Collection
Public ttsoiDate As Collection
Public ttsoiTime As Collection
Public ttReportUse As Collection


Sub ReportGenerationTool()
' set variables:
'...other code
' make organList an array list
Set organList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
'...more code

' set collections and add respective controls
Set ttComboBox = New Collection
With ttComboBox
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType1_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType2_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType3_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType4_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType5_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType6_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType7_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType8_ComboBox)
End With
ttComboBox.Item(1).AddItem "Test"
'**^THIS IS WHERE I GET THE 424 ERROR**'

Set ttAmountBlocked = New Collection
'...similar set up as above 
Set ttgcFileName = New Collection
'...similar set up as above 
Set ttsoiDate = New Collection
'...similar set up as above
Set ttsoiTime = New Collection
'...similar set up as above
Set ttReportUse = New Collection
'...similar set up as above 



' initialize report form
Call ReportForm_Initialize

' show report form
Report_Form.Show


End Sub
```

Normally, I had this line of code: `ttComboBox.Item(1).AddItem "Test"` (and others like it) in the ReportForm_Initialize() sub. 
Essentially I want to have this: Report_Form.TestType1_ComboBox.AddItem "Test" 
with this: ttComboBox(1).AddItem "Test"
If not with collections, how do I get this functionality?

Comment: please help, this has been frustrating me for some time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means that an object is expected but none is provided, so your collection does not actually contain objects (like a form control ComboBox), but something else.

I confirm this with a test scenario, screenshot below

If you look at the collection in the Locals window, you'll see that it holds string values, not form control/combobox objects!  Since a string value property doesn't have an `.Add` method, it raises the 424 error.

[image]

**Why does the collection contain strings instead of ComboBoxes?**

In VBA, parentheses normally force an *evaluation of an expression*

Sometimes this doesn't matter. For instance, `("hello")` evaluates the same as `"hello"`, but in the case of an object like a form control, parentheses will evaluate to the default property of that object (probably the `.Value` property).

**How to fix it??**

Simple, just remove the parentheses from the `.Add` statements.

```
With ttComboBox
    .Add Report_Form.TestType1_ComboBox
    .Add Report_Form.TestType2_ComboBox
    .Add ...etc.
```

Or you could be a little fancier and change the entire block:

```
With ttComboBox
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType1_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType2_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType3_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType4_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType5_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType6_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType7_ComboBox)
    .Add (Report_Form.TestType8_ComboBox)
End With
```

To this instead (assuming these are the only comboboxes on your form):

```
Dim cbox as Object

For each cbox in Report_Form.Controls
    If TypeName(cbox) = "ComboBox" Then
        ttComboBox.Add cBox
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Nice explanation David.